# Grid web component with paste from table

Tags: java, web-applications

I'm looking for a spreadsheet or grid type component. Specifically I need to allow a user to copy from an html table and paste into the spreadsheet. There is no need to support styling/fonts/calculations/etc.

I'm able to do this via the google docs spreadsheets, so it is possible, but I need to embed this into a java web application.

So far I've looked at:

- [ExtJs](http://www.extjs.com/)
- [SmartGWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/)
- [jquery grid plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)
- [RichFaces rich:datatable](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf)
- [zk spreadsheet](http://zssdemo.zkoss.org/zssdemo/index.zul)

and while they are all quite impressive in their own rights, none seem to allow copy from an html table and paste into the spreadsheet.